# What is the difference between Modify and Change in stat output

Tags: stat

What is the difference between Modify and Change in stat output? When I run this command:

```
stat myfile
```

I am getting two lines with identical timestamps:

```
Modify: 2015-03-24 12:34:56.12345678
Change: 2015-03-24 12:34:56.12345678
```

What is the deal?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

"Modify" is the timestamp of the last time the file's *content* has been modified which is often called "*mtime*".

"Change" is the timestamp of the last time the file's *inode* has been changed, like by changing permissions, ownership, file name, number of hard links. It's often called "*ctime*".